# Get keyboard show event in Unity3d

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I am making a game in unity3d for iPad only.

In one screen I need to take text input from user and for that I use [Input Field.](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-InputField.html)

I need to make some UI change when user open keyboard by taping Input Field. For that I need keyboard open(show) event. Input Field give me just two event 1. Text Change 2. Lost Focus. But I need get Focus event.

I read official document but can't find any relevant event. I search on internet for event, I get keystroke event but I need keyboard open event before user start typing.

In native iOS app we use `UITextFieldDelegate` Method `- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField`or `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification`. Is there any way in Unity3d to get this kind of behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For input field with the new UI there is an isFocused variable.

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.InputField.html

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.InputField-isFocused.html

```
#pragma strict
// Required when Using UI elements.
public class Example {
    public var mainInputField;
    function Update() {
        //If the input field is focused, change its color to green.
        if (mainInputField.GetComponent.<InputField>().isFocused == true) {
            mainInputField.GetComponent.<Image>().color = Color.green;
        }
    }
}
```

So if your field gets focused and it returns true you can execute some code. That is, if I understand you correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find anything that lets you know the InputField has been selected but a workaround may be setting the Interactable property to false and having an 'Edit' button near the field. When the 'Edit' button is pressed, you can change the UI elements and set the InputField.interactable = true.